# Unable to increase value in php

Tags: php

I have a function where, if the user enters the correct answer, the score should increment. The validation function is working fine, but the score is not incrementing. Initially, I defined it as 0 and then it should increment based on the answer, but it's not working.

```
    $score =0;
    function checkscore ($n, $ans)
    {
    global $score;
    $arr = array('a', 'd');
    if (($n == 1) && ($ans == (count(array_intersect($arr, $_POST['a'])) == count($arr))))  
    {
        $score++;
    }
    if (($n == 2) && ($ans == ($_POST['b'] == 'a'))) 
    {
        $score++;
    }

    if (($n == 3) && ($ans == "div[id='serenade']"))  
    {
        $score++;   
    }
    if (($n == 4) && ($ans != (($_POST['d1'] == 'B') && ($_POST['d2'] == 'C') && ($_POST['d3'] == 'A')))) 
    {
        $score++;   
    }

    return $score;
}
```

This is the function. Someone please help me.

Comment: How do you know it doen't increment?

Comment: Your function takes the variable `$ans` as a parameter, and then immediately overwrites it with a text string (`$ans = "div[id='serenade']";`). Why on earth are you doing this?

Comment: What is $ans = "div[id='serenade']"; doing?

Comment: im using ths echo "<p>Your score is ",checkscore($n,$ans),".</p>"; to print score

Comment: @gavin..thts nt doin anything its just an textinput answer.

Comment: @geomagas ive tried tht...but it is showing some error like undefined...score..

Comment: your snippet logic is done completely wrong.

Comment: ths is the error Notice: Undefined variable: score in C:\xampp\htdocs\assn3\question.php on line 167

Comment: @squeamishossifrage i have problem with $score, ok i got ntn to do with $ans, score got ntn to do with ans i guess....so if i am wrong can u plz explain me much better? plz

Comment: @fab why don't you pass the score as parameter

Comment: It's got _everything_ to do with `$ans`, since `$ans` takes part in the decision of whether to increment `$score` or not!

Comment: ok i removed tht....even then its getting incremented only till 1...wht should i do plz help me in function to increment for every correct answ...

Comment: @meda...how to pass score as a parameter..

Comment: @fab: No you didn't. It's still in your code. Also, declare `$score` outside the function, put a `global $score` inside it and remove that `$score=0`!!!

Comment: @geomagas ive edited the script once have a look, still its nt working itc getting incremented only once and stays unchnaged..wht to do plz help

Comment: Take another look at my answer and the relevant comment.

Comment: srry i didnt get u...

Answer (score 0):

This function will return 1 if `$n` is 3 or 4, 0 otherwise. The first two conditions will always be `false`, while the third will be `true` when `$n==3` and the fourth when `$n==4`.

So it *does increment* occasionally, but only up to 1...

Comment: @fab: Study php's [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). And when you're done, go over it again. If you don't know the basics, anything I'd try to tell you would be Greek to you.

Comment: ive tried some other method....to increment the score but still its not working please help me...                                           function checkscore ()
 {
 static $score = 0;
 if ($_SESSION['result']  == "Correct")
 $score ++;
 return $score;
 }

Comment: the above code in the comment is giving 1 if the condition is true and 0 if it is false its not increment further please help me out